# combinatorics with string array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I found a solution that prints all combinations of a string. The code below would have an output of:

Toyota black sedan
Honda black sedan
Toyota red sedan
Honda red sedan
Toyota black suv
Honda black suv
Toyota red suv
Honda red suv

```
String[][] sets = new String[][] {{"Toyota", "Honda"}, {"black", "red"}, {"sedan", "suv"}};
int[] state = new int[sets.length];
int p = 0;
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(sets[i][state[i]] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    state[p]++;

    while(state[p] == sets[p].length) {
        state[p] = 0;
        p++; 
        if (p == sets.length) return;
        state[p]++;
    }
    p = 0;  
}
```

Can someone please elaborate and explain what the second while loop is doing?

Comment: The entries of `state` are indices into the sub-arrays of `sets` which indicate the strings from those sub-arrays which make up the current combination being generated.  The second loop advances the indices in `state` to pick out the next combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state` is being used here to simulate a multiply nested for loop.  If you knew that there were 3 sets in `sets`, you could accomplish this with something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < sets[2].length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sets[1].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < sets[0].length; k++) {
             // form output from sets[0][k], sets[1][j], sets[2][i]
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work when you don't know how many indexes you'll need.

The `state` array in effect holds all the indexes of the nested `for` loops.  `state[0]` is the innermost index (`k` in the above example), `state[1]` is the next innermost index (`j`), etc.  This line (above the inner `while` loop):

```
state[p]++;
```

will increment `state[0]`, since `p` must always be 0 at this point (I think it should have been written `state[0]++` for clarity).  Now we need to handle the indexes that have reached their limit, which is what the second `while` loop does:

```
while(state[p] == sets[p].length) {
    state[p] = 0;
    p++; 
    if (p == sets.length) return;
    state[p]++;
}
```

Starting with `p==0`, we see if `state[0]` has reached its limit (i.e. `k==sets[0].length` in the nested `for` example).  If it has, we simulate exiting that `for` loop by resetting that index to 0 (ahead of time), then moving out to the next outer `for` loop.  Now `p==1`, so we'll be incrementing `state[1]` which is `j` in the nested `for` example.  `state[p]++` increments `j`, then we go back to the top of the `while` loop to see if `j` has reached its limit.  If so, we do the same thing--reset `j` to 0, then look at `state[2]` which is equivalent to `i`, and so on...